# Clean data with unwanted quotes

Tags: python, r

I have a csv file that contains client number, address  and premium. It's exported from another system, so the fields have quotes. While importing in R, I face an issue due to unwanted quotes and commas inside string. See example (Client 1 and 2 are correct, client 3 has the issue)

```
Client number Address                               Premium
"1"            "Building5, Street 30,NY"              1000
"2"           "Building7, Street 10,NY"               1000
"3"           "Building 7\", Street 10,NY"            1000
```

Because of this , R reads it as a new 4th column which I don't want. How do I get rid of it programmatically. I am ok with an R or Python based solution that cleans up the csv . If correcting the problem is difficult, even deleting client 3 is an acceptable solution

Tried doing this in python but doesn't help

```
import csv

def remove_special_prob(s):
return ''.join(c for c in s if c not in ('\"'))


with open("Client.csv","rb") as infile, open("Client_new.csv","wb") as outfile:
reader = csv.reader(infile)
writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
for line in reader:
    writer.writerow([remove_special_prob(elem) for elem in line])
```

Comment: Is the backslash in `\"` _present in the file_, or is it what is _printed_ by R? Can you do a copy-and-paste from Notepad, vi, emacs or another external text editor?

Comment: It's in the original csv file

Comment: Oh, updated my answer for the same.

Comment: Did you try `pandas` to read the CSV? their `read_csv` [method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) is very good. What is the delimiter? are it tabs or spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in the actual csv, then use `return s.replace('\"', '')`.

Your code isn't working because you are iterating over each letter, but then comparing it so 2 letters, viz., `\"` together. Basically, your `c` will become `\` first and then `"` over the iteration, but would never equal `\"`.

**Edit**

For replacing -

```
def remove_special_prob(s):
    return s.replace('\"', '')
```

For skipping special problem lines

```
with open("Client.csv","rb") as infile, open("Client_new.csv","wb") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in reader:
         if line.count('"') > 6:
             continue
         writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to solve the problem. There are few rows that are extremely troublesome. Is there a way to do this - I know the number of columns (3) . Therefore expected number of quotes should be 6 in a valid record. How can I remove all lines from the csv that have >6 quotes (") ?

Comment: Skip the line with a `continue` when `line.count('"') > 6`.

Comment: `with open("Client.csv","rb") as infile, open("Client_new.csv","wb") as outfile:
    filtered_csv = (line for line in infile if not line.count('"') > 42)
    reader = csv.reader(filtered_csv)
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for line in reader:
       writer.writerow()`  tried this but does seem to work (sorry beginner in python)

Comment: Updated my answer for that, kindly check.

Answer (score 1):

In Python you can use `pandas`'s `read_csv` which is quite versatile

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

text = StringIO("""Client number\tAddress\tPremium
"1"\t"Building5, Street 30,NY"\t1000
"2"\t"Building7, Street 10,NY"\t1000
"3"\t"Building 7\", Street 10,NY"\t1000""")

df = pd.read_csv(text, sep='\t')
df['Address'] = df['Address'].str.replace('"', '')
# df.to_clipboard()
```

results in

```
    Client number   Address Premium
0   1   Building5, Street 30,NY 1000
1   2   Building7, Street 10,NY 1000
2   3   Building 7, Street 10,NY    1000
```

Comment: The challenge is I need to import this csv to R to run some pre-written code. If I import to pandas, I'll have to write back to csv and import back in R . Now  my address field already has multiple commas (that are valid). Exporting to csv again will mess it up due to these commas

Comment: you can have python export it as csv with `;` as seperator

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can read the file using `readLines`, remove the string `\"`, and convert it to a data frame:

```
txt <- readLines("client.csv")
df <- read.csv(text=gsub('\\\\\"', "", txt))
```

Comment: Tried readlines but the second step takes an enormous amount of time My code was     read.table(textConnection(txt))

Comment: It takes the same amount of time as it would to read the file directly. If you want faster alternatives to `read.csv`, ask another question.